# Django_filters ModelChoiceFilter display text input

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using Django_filters to create filters. I have to use ModelChoiceFilter due to foreign key in models. The filter automatically returns a drop down list, is there a way to display a text input box instead of drop down list when I use ModelChoiceFilter? Thanks

code:

`GPA = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(name='persontoschool__GPA',                                      queryset=PersonToSchool.objects.values_list('GPA',flat=True).distinct(),to_field_name='GPA', lookup_expr='gte')`

Comment: You are posting backend code. and you want the fronted to change? Post the HTML code where the dropdown list appears. Or am I misunderstanding the Question?

Answer (score 0):

`Filter`s actually construct an underlying Django form `Field` in order to perform input validation, rendering, etc... Arguments that the filter does not expect are passed to the form field's constructor. If you want to use a plain text input, then you can simply pass the appropriate `widget` to the `Filter`.